# When should I use host gpu versus snapshot in a virtual device using the avd?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

I wonder which one to choose if I just want to use the virtual device for educational purposes, namely to learn to use them for testing and debugging my apps.

Is there performance differences? Or just usage differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are significant performance differences. 
Everything you need to know is here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51739/what-is-snapshot-and-use-host-gpu-emulation-options-for